# error en php y postgresql clases y metodos

Tags: php, postgresql

Necesito enviar desde un archivo `PHP` a otro de **conexion.php** una sentencia sql.. pero no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal en el siguiente es el código:

> versión de php 5.2.3. versión de apache 2.2.4.

Cuando ejecuto el archivo de conexión, este llega hasta `ejecutarSQL()` pero al parecer no reconoce la `query`.

```
require_once("conexion.php ");
class obtener extends class_conexion  {
    public $_sql; 
    public $_consulta; 

    public function consultaSQL()
    { 
        $this->_sql = new class_conexion();    
        $this->_consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios"; 
        $result = $this->ao_sql->ejecutarSQL($this->_consulta);
    }
}
$obtener = new obtener();
$obtener->consultaSQL(); 

-----------------------------
conexion.php:

class class_conexion {
    public $conexion="";
    public $_consulta="";

    public function abrirConexion()
    { 
        $this->conexion = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=demo user=postgres password=123456");

        $estatus = pg_connection_status($this->conexion);

        if($estatus === PGSQL_CONNECTION_OK){
            print "OK'";    
        }else{
            print "error";
        }
        return $this->conexion;
    }

    public function ejecutarSQL(){

        $ejecutoQuery = pg_query($this->conexion, $this->_consulta); 

        if($ejecutoQuery){
            echo "<br>funciona";
        }else{
            echo "<br>error!!!";
        }
    }
}
$abrirC = new class_Conexion();
$abrirC->abrirConexion();
$abrirC->ejecutarSQL();
```

Comment: `$this->_consulta`es nulo siempre en `ejecutarSQL()`